# RQT python plugin crashes randomly, but often

Tags: plugin, ros-hydro, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ROS Hydro on Ubuntu precise.

I started with the robot steering RQT plugin (http://wiki.ros.org/rqt/Plugins) which is a python plugin and I tweaked it to show about 20 or so of my robot Topic values in real time.  Most of the robot Topic values are being published at 5 or 10 Hz.  This new plugin likes to crash quite often, but there's no one thing that I can do to make it crash.

Do python RQT plugins have trouble displaying a lot of 5 to 10 Hz data?  Should I throttle the data specifically for my user interface?  Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196611/rqt-python-plugin-crashes-randomly,-but-often/) by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) on ROS Answers with karma: 486 on 2014-11-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

RQT plugins such as rqt_plot regularly handle high data rates (100Hz+) without issue.

If your plugin (or any program, really) crashes randomly at different places, you probably have some combination of memory corruption and threading bugs. Keeping in mind that the drawing code and ROS callbacks are often serviced from different threads, I would go through your code and make sure that you have locking or thread-safe data structures in the appropriate places.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1